# Регулярные выражения, символ "^"

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Вот только недавно начал *JavaScript* и можете помочь либо "пнуть" в нужном направлении. 
Как проверить в регулярных выражениях символ `^`?
Например:

```
 var reg = 'hello^friend';
 reg.split(/^|h/);
```

(как написать это корректно?)

Comment: экранировать его с помощью обратного слэша

Comment: Как подметили комментом выше: `reg.split(/\^/);`. Если нужно найти какие-то спец символы, их нужно экранировать в регулярке

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если нужно найти какие-то спецсимволы, например, `^` `.` `$` `*`, их нужно экранировать в регулярке слешем: `\^` `\.` `\$` `\*`:

```js
 var reg = 'hello^friend';
 console.log(reg.split(/\^|h/));
```